# How to say goodbye to your supervisor before the new year

Tags: advisor

I am meeting my supervisor tomorrow and it is the last time I see her this year. I am not a native English speaker and don't know how to say goodbye and wish happy things.I am wondering if somebody can help .e in this regard.?

Comment: How this is related to academia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> See you next year, and happy holidays!

You could also say "Merry Christmas" if your supervisor is Christian, but if your supervisor is not Christian it's possible (unlikely, but possible) that she's offended by that ([example](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/asia/brunei-cancels-christmas-sultan-warns-those-celebrating-could-face-up-to-five-years-in-jail-a6782561.html)). "Happy holidays" sidesteps the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just wish her a merry Christmas and tell her that you will see her after the new year.

Answer (score 0):

Have a happy and safe Holidays.